# What needs to be considered while buying a LED TV for my xbox

Tags: xbox-360, kinect

What are the things to be considered while buying a screen for an XBox 360 with Kinect?

- Size
- Resolution
- Brightness
- Backlight Module
- View Angle
- HD Ready or Full HD

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the screen size matters for the Kinect itself. However, you *don't want to go too big or too small*; too big and it'll be **harder** to control, to small and the **cursor will go everywhere**. From what I've seen, you might want something a bit **bigger** than 24".

Comment: Agreed. screen size has nothing to do with how Kinect works and is only related to how well you see the game you want to play! If the OP meant the thickness of the screen needed to place Kinect, there are a few mounts you can buy to place the sensor but you can also just put it on the same stand as the TV.

Comment: @hsuk No, just size.

Comment: If you are into fighting games, I'd advise you to check if the TV has a "game mode". LED TV's tend to have some input lag and this can get in the way when executing combos. However in game mode this is minimized. I think most TV's nowadays have game modes but it can't hurt to check.

Answer (score 0):

No, the only thing that really matters is the space between you and the Kinect sensor (you'll typically want at least 2 or 3 meters if possible; not 100% sure about the actual specs).

Theoretically, you can play any Kinect game with your TV turned off.

The only games that are screen dependent are classic light gun games, because those used the displayed screen to determine whether you hit or not.

But for all modern games - no matter whether it's Kinect or Move - all that really matters is the distance between you and the camera, as that defines the space where you're able to move, where the system is able to see you, etc.

Of course, a too small or too big screen can be a problem for you personally (e.g. you're no longer able to read text at the recommended distance), but it will never interfere with the actual input/control system.

Comment: It's really personal preference. There's no "one size fits all", but I'd try to get at least 24" or 27".

Comment: These days always try to get a full HD TV, i.e. one with 1080 vertical resolution. Otherwise you won't be able to enjoy any next-gen console or bluray videos in their full resolution. This might mean you'll have to pay a bit more, but it's usually worth the extra money.

Comment: hmm, I could see 1080p and 1080i, I am wondering the difference in between them

Comment: 1080p draws the full image once per frame; 1080i cheats by drawing half the image every frame. You'll hardly notice the difference, but overall 1080p offers a slightly better image quality, especially on bigger screens.

Answer (score 0):

I believe an important point you are overlooking is Input Lag.
The last thing you will want is a display that is the right size, with great color, good viewing angle, etc that has a delay between your button 'clicks' and their action on the screen.
I have found this web site ([Display Lag Database](http://www.displaylag.com/display-database/) ) to be a big help when I was purchasing a new monitor for my PS3/Xbox360 setup after discovering the my New 42" LG TV is virtually unusable because of the Input Lag.